# NavigationDrawer with Submenu

Tags: gluon

I would like to implement some functionalities like submenu on NavigationDrawer using "afterburner" but I have found some issues, what is the best practice, destroy and recreate the DefaultNavigationDrawer with submenus or have one NavigationDrawer for each module?

I have used the answer code on: [Gluon mobile app NavigationDrawer back button issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36217473/gluon-mobile-app-navigationdrawer-back-button-issue)

but I have a more complex situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `NavigationDrawer` object from `DefaultNavigationDrawer`, and after that you can add as many items (these are just nodes), as you want.

If these items are not `ViewItem` instances, you will have to take care of the action to perform when the user selects them.

Using the Glisten-Afterburner template, this is how you get the drawer in the first place, in `AppViewManager::registerViewsAndDrawer`:

```
public static void registerViewsAndDrawer(MobileApplication app) {
    for (AppView view : REGISTRY.getViews()) {
        view.registerView(app);
    }

    NavigationDrawer.Header header = new NavigationDrawer.Header("Gluon Mobile",
            "Multi View Project",
            new Avatar(21, new Image(GluonGAf1.class.getResourceAsStream("/icon.png"))));

    DefaultDrawerManager drawerManager = new DefaultDrawerManager(app, header, REGISTRY.getViews()) {
        {
            // Get the drawer:
            NavigationDrawer drawer = getDrawer();
        }
    }; 
    drawerManager.installDrawer();
}
```

Now you can add `NavigationDrawer.Item` to its `items` collection:

```
public static void registerViewsAndDrawer(MobileApplication app) {
    for (AppView view : REGISTRY.getViews()) {
        view.registerView(app);
    }

    NavigationDrawer.Header header = new NavigationDrawer.Header("Gluon Mobile",
            "Multi View Project",
            new Avatar(21, new Image(GluonGAf1.class.getResourceAsStream("/icon.png"))));

    // create items
    NavigationDrawer.Item subItem1 = new NavigationDrawer.Item("Sub Item 1", MaterialDesignIcon.ADD.graphic());
    NavigationDrawer.Item subItem2 = new NavigationDrawer.Item("Sub Item 2", MaterialDesignIcon.ADD_BOX.graphic());
    NavigationDrawer.Item subItem3 = new NavigationDrawer.Item("Sub Item 3", MaterialDesignIcon.ADD_LOCATION.graphic());

    DefaultDrawerManager drawerManager = new DefaultDrawerManager(app, header, REGISTRY.getViews()) {
        {
            // Get the drawer:
            NavigationDrawer drawer = getDrawer();
            // Add items
            drawer.getItems().addAll(new Separator(), subItem1, subItem2, subItem3);
            // TODO: provide action based on item selected
            drawer.selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> System.out.println("Selected item " + nv));
        }
    }; 
    drawerManager.installDrawer();
}
```

You will get this:

[image: Navigation Drawer with items]

Comment: Thank you so much! By your answer the problem was solved! [basic links](https://www.globalsuite.com.br/videos/DrawerSubmenu.gif)

Comment: <img src="https://globalsuite.com.br/videos/DrawerSubmenu.gif"; width="100" height="100">